# Certificates Problems: Apple WWDRCA certificate "signed by an unknown authorith"

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, certificate

I've been having trouble re-establishing my build environment. It's worked fine in the past, but in the midst of running archive processes, I've managed to throw myself back a couple of days.

I've done TN2250 patiently.

Everything goes smooth — except no matter what I do, the Apple WWDRCA.cer shows up in the login (default) keychain in my Keychain Access as "This certificate was signed by an unknown authority." I've tried getting the certificate from a link from Apple's iOS Provisioning Profile as well as hard links — not that it should matter, but I'm desperate at this point.

My developmer and distribution certificates appear to be fine — there are no errors next to their view in Keychain Access and they contain my private keys, as best as I can tell (click arrow, down it goes, there's my key.)

I notice this even before I add the certificate. I mean — it's coming from Apple? It's a file. Why would it not be signed correctly?

The errors vary with the various things I try. But the recurring one is

```
CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I've tried & referred to:

[CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747857/cssmerr-tp-not-trusted-error)

and the specific points in TN2250 here:

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG19

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just seem to have figured this out. I haven't seen this answer anywhere, so I'll answer my own question. It seems as though my Keychain was missing a valid "Apple Computer, Inc. Root Certificate" and "Apple Inc. Root Certificate". As soon as I installed these, my certificates became "green" and valid.

I got these certificates from here: http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/

Comment: I too have the same issue. But even after downloading these certificates, the problem persists. Where did u copy those certificates? I copied in to the login-certificates tab in keychain access.

Comment: It's been awhile, so I don't recall precisely — but I believe they are meant to go in your Keychain. If you click in the "Category" box which in mine is on the bottom left pane, you'll see an item called "My Certificates." Mine then appear in the main pane on the right.